# Is the nose design on the Resurgent-class Star Destroyer Finalizer linked to Kylo Ren?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

The new Resurgent-class Star Destroyer in *The Force Awakens* has a nose design resembling Kylo Ren's light-saber.

[image]

Is this just a coincidence that Kylo Ren's light-saber looks the same or does it have some meaning to it?

Comment: It's so the First Order can give an entire planet the finger before blasting it away.

Comment: @RichS, LOL, didn't think of that.

Comment: In-universe? Or out? Because @Richard's answer gives the "in" explanation. I would be fairly certain that it was on the mind of the production team putting this together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unknown, but *unlikely*.

According to the Star Wars: Incredible Cross-Sections factbook, the Resurgent is part of a new class of Star Destroyer, larger and better armed than those seen in the Imperial Era and sporting heavier armour, more weapons and an improved design. This apparently includes front-mounted tractor beam emitters.

[image]

That being said, it seems highly unlikely that Snoke's designers would be taking advice from Ren as to how to build a ship and where to put bits. It also seems highly unlikely that Ren would want to build a ship that's intentionally evocative of his own *failure* to build a workable lightsaber without having to jerry-rig plasma vents onto it.

Comment: Snope? Do you mean Supreme Leader Severus Snape?

Comment: @recognizer He was referring to [this](http://www.snopes.com/false-star-wars-fan-beaten-sharing-spoilers/).

Comment: snope, snope, severus snope.

Comment: @tombull89 - [Dumbledore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tx1XIm6q4r4)

Comment: @Richard yes, that was what I was also referencing

Comment: @tombull89 - yes, but you forgot to post the link so that we could all share in your glorious reference.